# CSS using selectors input[type=date], input[type=time] only works for first selector

Tags: css

This is a strange one that has me stumped.

I'm defining my CSS using the same formatting for multiple selectors on a given class. The traditional format is to separate them with commas like so:

```
.class selector, selector {
     (formatting code)
}
```

This normally works fine as written. However, I have one instance where it does not work correctly, and I'm stumped as to why...  Here's what I'm doing:

```
.myClass input[type=date], input[type=time] {
     (formatting code)
}
```

So, in this instance the FIRST selector is formatted, but the second is not. In this example, DATE is formatted but TIME is not. If I reverse the type=date and type=time, then TIME is formatted and DATE is not.

What is particularly confusing is that I use this same format in another area that works just fine. The only difference is instead of date and time, I use Text and Password like so:

```
.myClass input[type=text], input[type=password] {
         (formatting code)
}
```

This one works fine and the formatting is applied to both the text and password fields.

My workaround for the non-working date/time css example has simply been to make a separate declaration for each:

```
.myClass input[type=date] {
         (formatting code)
}

.myClass input[type=time] {
         (same formatting code)
}
```

This works just fine, but I'm trying to understand if this is a limitation of some sort or if I'm doing something wrong. Can't seem to find any explanation that answers this so far, so thought I'd post as a question to see if someone has an idea.

Thanks guys!

Comment: you need the `.myClass` after the comma - once you put a comma, you start a new selector

Comment: `.myClass input[type=date], input[type=time]` does NOT select the time input that is a child of `myClass`, you can't chain selectors like that.

Comment: Thanks guys. What's weird is that it works in some instances and does not in others! Looks like css was accepting my bad habits!

Comment: consider using Sass or Less, css preprocessors allow you to chain parents / children in form of a tree

Comment: Or use `:is` - `.myClass :is(input[type=date], input[type=time])` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is